# Gridview Error :A call to Bind was not well formatted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have following code for gridview :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="N/A">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblENGNA" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("N/A") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When i run this its giving me error for above section that:

> Parser Error Message: A call to Bind was not well formatted.  Please
>   refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind.

Error Image:

[image]

**Note:** my query(which binds grid) contains field N/A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added `[N/A]` in bind and it worked.

Its as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblENGNA" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[N/A]") %>'>
```