# Using Gridview and getting scrollable cells?

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

I am using Gridview and I want to have the cells scrollable. I already have a `div` that scrolls the whole table, but I need to individual cells to be kept to a certain max width and a scrollbar be created for cells that have data that would exceed that.

I have tried adding `<rowstyle Wrap="false"/>` this made the data stop wrapping, which I wanted, but now the rows are very very wide. Which I don't want.

I found several suggestions that say to add a `div` around the `Gridview` which I did and added a css rule like `overflow-x:auto;width:200px;` this did not help the cells are still very very wide.

I have the Gridview setup like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="PMDataGrid"
    datasourceid="PMDataSource"
    ondatabound="PMDataGrid_DataBound"
    autogeneratecolumns="false"
    emptydatatext="No Data Available"
    allowpaging="true"
    pagesize="25"
    runat="server" 
    showheader="true"
    showfooter="true"
    DataKeyNames="PROJECT"
    allowsorting="true"
    style="overflow-x:auto"
    headerstyle-cssclass="FixedHeader">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" height="50px" Wrap="false" Width="250px" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#e5e5e5" ForeColor="Black" height="50px" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="#fff" />
```

I would like to be able to have a max-width of 250px and have a scrollbar when the data is too long, but I am unable to find a solution. I am fairly new to web apps in asp.net.

I have added this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COE_%_RCVD_BY_LINE" SortExpression="COE_%_RCVD_BY_LINE">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Lable70" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("COE_%_RCVD_BY_LINE") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Which produced this error:

> Parser Error Message: A call to Bind was not well formatted.  Please refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind.

I think it's the `%` that is causing the error. Is there a way to keep the `%` and have it work?

I forgot to add the surrounding `<div></div>`. It now looks like this:
    
        
            
                '>

How and I have CSS setup like this:

```
.Gridview {
    overflow-x:auto;
    width:250px;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I have this setup correctly, but still the columns are very very wide:
[image: Very Very Wide Column]
and the rules in the CSS don't seem to be applying:
[image: Rules]

Comment: Have you tried this ? -> https://forums.asp.net/t/2037462.aspx?create+a+scrollbar+in+a+gridview+cell

Comment: Ya you should probably use the `<ItemTemplate>` and wrap all content in a scrollable div like @theoretisch posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to scroll in a cell of a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242916/is-it-possible-to-scroll-in-a-cell-of-a-gridview)

Comment: @theoretisch I have not tried that before. I have added it and run into a new problem.

Comment: @zgood I have not tried the `<ItemTemplate>` before. I have not seen anything about it till now. I've added it in, but it created a new error. Any ideas? I updated my question.

Comment: @Mike Make sure you nest the `<ItemTemplate>` under the `<Columns>` node and `<TemplateField>` nodes. See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)

Comment: @zgood it ended up being a syntax error. I forgot the `>` at the end of the `</itemTemplate`

Comment: @zgood this did not work though. It made no change in how the data is presented. The comment fields are still very very wide.

Comment: @theoretisch this did not work. The columns are still very very wide.

Comment: @Mike you can name the headertext like you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18101439/5859685

Comment: @theoretisch I was able to figure out the `%` problem. But the rest is still not working. The columns are still very very wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it figured out.
I had the CSS file with the style, this did not work. When I added the style to the `div` inline then it works, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DESCRIPTION" SortExpression="DESCRIPTION">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Gridview" style="overflow-x:auto; max-width:250px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Lable1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DESCRIPTION") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This now works to add the scrollbar to any field that goes over the `250px` max that I have set.

This can mostly be found in the similar question: [Is it possible to scroll in a cell of a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242916/is-it-possible-to-scroll-in-a-cell-of-a-gridview)

But I did learn that the `style` has to be inline for it to work. Having the `style` in the CSS file did not work.